# Rally "Actuals" field not visible within the task if there is no value entered

Tags: field, task, show, rally

I create a task board like here: https://help.rallydev.com/task-board
and i config to show "Actuals" field on task card but the "Actuals" field not show up when it has no value. So how to I show it and instead by zero value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly by design, so that the card is not cluttered up by a bunch of fields that do not have a value.  Unfortunately the one place where this falls down is when it's empty but you want to edit it to give it a value but can't because it's not there.

Probably the best workaround is to just loop over all the cards on the board when it is loaded and set a value of 0 in each record and refresh its card.  An example board config:

```
{
    listeners: {
        load: function(board) {
            _.each(board.getColumns(), function(column) {
                _.each(column.getCards(), function(card) {
                    card.getRecord().set('Actuals',
                       card.getRecord().get('Actuals') || 0);
                    card.reRender();
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I think your solution maybe work but It could down board performance when load. Do you think that?

I have another idea that is overwrite directly in Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.CardContentLeft class. That is class for show information on card. Just set Actuals value to 0 instead of null. Of course this will make code of app is bigger but it not down performance.

Comment: you're probably right.  i bet your solution is faster!